# Integrate aspnet authentication module to flex .net web application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, apache-flex, weborb

We have asp.net authentication web pages with backend MySQL. It has social log-in and api used to bring demographics of user when registering. It uses MySQL as backend, Visual Studio 2010, C# code behind, .net framework 4.0
We have another application that’s being developed in Flex 4.0 with WebORB
I wanted to use authentication and registration of ASP.net web pages and allow user to view web application developed in Flex with .net.

1. We have used HTTPService and RemoteObject to bring the data from .net application and this data is displaying on our flex application successfully.
2. But now we want to integrate our ASP.Net pages(registration and login page) into our flex application and these pages should be called from flex application only.
3. I have tried to call .aspx page from flex application using URLLoader class, I have added the below code in the click event of the button control as below:

```
var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
var PATH:String = "http://localhost:49531/WebSite1/Home.aspx";
var textRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(PATH);
loader.load(textRequest);
```

but the page did not get opened.

4. Please let me know how to call .aspx pages from flex application.

Comment: What do you mean by "the page did not get opened"?  Are you trying to display Home.aspx in your Flex app?  Parse the data?  Launch a browser instance?  Can you load Home.aspx in your browser?  Have you run Wireshark to inspect the communication between Flex and your aspx site?

Comment: I am trying to load home.aspx in the browser. I did not inspect using wireshark, can you provide any link or help for doing so. Specially for flex projects.

Comment: Is your Flex app running in a browser already, or is it an Adobe AIR app?  As to URLLoader, that's the wrong approach; it will load the HTML from Home.aspx (or whatever URL you pass), but it doesn't have a display component.

Comment: @Brian, my flex web application running in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `navigateToUrl()`.  As shown in [the Flex Examples blog](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/29/launching-new-browser-windows-from-flex/), you can simply do:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
navigateToURL(urlRequest, String(comboBox.selectedItem));
```